# Convert custom gradle file to gradle kts on Android project folder

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Currently I have couple of custom gradle files in my project, example
`jacoco.gradle` when I tried to create a new/rename to `jacoco.gradle.kts` Android studio does not recognize the .kts file, I already renamed and migrated successfully `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts` do I need to do an extra step to have a custom .kts file in the root of the project? if use `buildSrc` works correctly, however I don't have access to some important task like catalog libraries (I read that I need extra code for this) but also not the Android specific task (like flavour names and so on), I saw some projects in Github with custom gradle.kts files in the root of the project, how I can achieve this?